# Where clause on join query laravel 4.2

Tags: mysql, laravel, join, laravel-4, where-clause

I have 2 tables 'users' and 'instantUsers'. I want to join them on users.id = instantUsers.user_id and want to add 2 where clauses on the resulting. I'm not getting how to do both. The query I'm using is -

```
DB::table('users')
    ->join('instantUsers', function($join) use ($userId) {
        $join->on('users.id', '=', 'instantUsers.user_id');
    })
    ->where('instantUsers.instantMode', '=', '1')
    ->where (function($query) use ($userId) {
        $query->where('instantUsers.user_id', '!=', $userId);
    })
    ->get();
```

Comment: I'm getting status code 500 at the front end

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one maybe this will help you:

```
DB::table('users as table1')->join('instantUsers as table2','table1.id','=','table2.fkId') ->where('table2.instantMode','=','1')->where('table2.user_id','!=',$userId)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `'instantUsers.instantMode','=','1'` expression can be done in a join, resulting in a better performance.
I would write it like this

```
DB::table('users')
    ->join('instantUsers', function($join) use ($userId) {
        $join
            ->on('users.id', '=', 'instantUsers.user_id')
            ->on('instantUsers.instantMode', '=', 1);
    })
    ->where('users.id', '!=', $userId)
    ->get();
```

Comment: What exactly isn`t working? If there are any errors, what are they? Can you also provide the database schema?

Comment: It is not showing any error, just status code 500. Also, even a simple join is not working.

Comment: Can you enable debug mode and provide the stacktrace?